# numeros con comas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen día, supongamos tengo el siguiente número de ejemplo:

```
var numero=12457.13
```

deseo poder darle formato a ese número, para obtenerlo separado por comas, el resultado sería así:

```
12,457.13
```

Leyendo vi que se debería de lograr usando el método `toLocaleString()` de javascript, pero no me funcionó. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sé por que no te funcionaría la función `toLocaleString()`, pero habías buscado en el sitio correcto. Te dejo un ejemplo de uso con tu caso:

```js
var numero = 12457.13
const localeString = numero.toLocaleString('en');

console.log(localeString);
```

Comment: Quizá la clave haya sido el culture de Inglés "en", que tú si has facilitado en el ejemplo, y que por lo que veo en la pregunta faltaba por definir.

Comment: encontré mi problema, era que el dato que estaba intentando convertir no estaba como un número, lo arregle haciendo un Number("valor") antes del toLocaleString :D y el culture "en" si ayudó, sin eso no me funcionaba

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza este código:

```
 var formatNumber = {
 separador: ",", // separador para los miles
 sepDecimal: '.', // separador para los decimales
 formatear:function (num){
 num +='';
 var splitStr = num.split('.');
 var splitLeft = splitStr[0];
 var splitRight = splitStr.length > 1 ? this.sepDecimal + splitStr[1] : '';
 var regx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
 while (regx.test(splitLeft)) {
 splitLeft = splitLeft.replace(regx, '$1' + this.separador + '$2');
 }
 return this.simbol + splitLeft +splitRight;
 },
 new:function(num, simbol){
 this.simbol = simbol ||'';
 return this.formatear(num);
 }
}

$num = formatNumber.new(12457.13); //retorna 12,457.13
console.log($num);
```